# Javascript Easing not working correctly - EaseInCirc?

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script, easing

using Javascript in Photoshop Scripting, I wish to change the Opacity of X layers from Opacity 0 to Opacity 100, but in a gradual/slow to lastly hastened manner e.g. 'EaseInCirc' I believe.

The code I am using (not successfully) is: https://jsfiddle.net/09onhmy7/

```
numberOfLayers = 20;
myOpacity = 0;
x=0;
for(i = 0 ; i < numberOfLayers ; i++){
    myIncrements = EaseExpo(i, 1, x, numberOfLayers);
    x = myIncrements + myIncrements;
    myOpacity = myOpacity + parseInt(myIncrements,10); 
    if (myOpacity > 100) {myOpacity = 100 ;} 
    document.write(myOpacity+",");
}
```

I found the EaseExpo(EaseInCirc) code on-line (http://gizma.com/easing/):

```
// t = current time
// b = start value
// c = change in value
// d = duration
// (t and d) can be frames

function EaseExpo(t, b, c, d) {
  //EaseInCirc
    return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
}
```

…but so far the code returns values that don't distribute as expected from 0 - 100 -- and most likely never will, as I don't know how to go about transposing them to suit the 0-100 bounds.

Basically, I'm trying to create an iteration of values (that aren't lineal) from 0 - X to represent a rate of change that slowly ramps up to maximum velocity (I'm pretty sure it’s a squareroot graph/function?) that I'm trying to replicate.

The values that will be input will always start at 0, but could have a maximum of any value.
**The trick is, I need to be able to always transpose the end values into a 0-100 result.**

```
e.g. A) 40 values = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,32,34,36,39,42,46,51,58,68,83,100

e.g. B) 18 values = 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,20,23,27,32,39,49,64,88,100
```

I cant for the life of me work out how to do it -- or should I be using different math to achieve what I want?
Many thanks in advance, Livy

Comment: whats the issue EaseInCirc speeds up towards the end this seems to be doing just that?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JoeWarner - yes, EaseInCirc appears to work fine - it's getting the values to stay between 0 and 100 that I cant get my head around. e.g. if my max value was [20] values = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,18,20,23,28,36 --- and if it was [50] values = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,36,38,40,42,44,47,50,53,57,62,68,76,87,100,100,100